# UITextField "not a structure or union"?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In my app, I am trying to perform an operation on a string when the user enters text. In the viewDidLoad method:

```
[textView addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

Here is the declaration for that method:

```
-(void)textFieldDidChange:(id)sender {
 sender = (UITextField *)sender;
 [self operationForInput:sender.text inTextField:sender];
}
```

But when I try to compile, it gives me the "Request for member 'text' in something not a structure on union" error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The local variable `sender` is of type `id`.  You're trying to access the `text` property of `sender`, which doesn't exist in `id` (it's a property of `UITextField`).

The line `sender = (UITextField *)sender` is useless—you downcast from `id` to `UITextField*`, but then when you assign back to `sender`, you're upcasting back to `id`.  You should change your code to this:

```
UITextField *textField = sender;  // casts from id to other types are implicit
[self operationForInput:textField.text inTextField:textField];
```

Comment: Thats it. Didn't know that about casting. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should go with something like:

```
-(void)textFieldDidChange:(UITextField *)textField {
    if(textField == textField1) {
        /* do something for textfield 1 */
    }
    if(textField == textField2) {
        /* do something for textfield2 */
    }
}
```

Making sure your textFields are defined in your header.

Also, `[textView addTarget...` wont need to be used if you use the above delegate.